# Why this web page is suddenly being displayed wrongly in IE7

Tags: php, internet-explorer-7, rendering

I'm having a problem that's intriguing me. I decided make a few changes (in a link and inserting metatags) in the index.php file from my company's site: http://www.expresssignproducts.com and after I uploaded the header pictures were all misaligned in IE7 (others were fine). So I uploaded the previous version of the file... same bad display... then I got a copy from the latest backup, still the bad display? How can it be? Why would IE7 suddenly decide to render it badly?

Regards,

Eduardo
P.S. I'm not the web developer/designer for the site.

Comment: is it possible that your tags were malformed? that could cause some havoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems...

1) There are two `<body>` tags.

I see in the source:

```
</head>
<body onload="MM_preloadImages...
<div id="Header">
  <script...
  </script>
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages...
```

2) The "Home" image is floated left and the "Customer Registration" image is floated right. Remove the float-right and that will resolve the problem in IE7.

Comment: I think it came 2 times because the original file has a php include. I removed the class="right" attribute for the customer registration picture. Now they are all together, but still much better than the mess from before. I'm waiting to hear from the web designers yet to see what they offer as a better permanent solution. Thank you very much for your guidance.